# Processmaker 4.0 Echoing Data on the same screen

Tags: processmaker

I am trying to make a code for a watcher so that when the select list option "yes" when asking "is your permanent address the same as your current address?" is selected it copies the values from current address entry fields and repeats them into the permanent address entry fields on the same screen. Both entry fields are on the same screen, it does not pull data from a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use calculated properties for this.
https://processmaker.gitbook.io/processmaker/designing-processes/design-forms/screens-builder/manage-computed-properties/add-a-computed-property-to-a-screen

I made a quick example for you here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1d3DA_EZ-pHcV3Q-G29Y-6n-qfxyUfRUc/view?usp=sharing

Basically, there is a visibility rule set to only show bar if the toggle is set. Then in the calculated properties we set the value of bar equal to that of foo.

In your case, it would just be the value of the address. You would need to do it for each field that you wanted to echo in that way.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Do you happen to know if there is any way if the option asking if their Permanent address is the same as their current one is set to no, that allows entry into the Permanent Address fields instead of being view only. Or would i have to make a whole other set of entry fields.